# Undo all scheduled task in SVN

Tags: svn

I searched for a proper solution, but I wasn't able to find any. 
I messed up my SVN repository a little bit. I do have local changes and I accidentally added some undesired data. So i did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083242/undo-svn-add-without-reverting-local-edits); unfortunately for too many files. It scheduled a lot of deletions. I re-added some files and due to the amount I got angry:)

So, my question, is there a way to undo all scheduled tasks (Add, Delete) without losing my local changes (contrary to `svn revert`)?

Sorry, I can't see the forest for the trees anymore and I hope this answer isn't too stupid.

PS : SVN Version 1.8.10

Comment: Just copy the working copy somewhere else (i.e. make a backup), then run `svn revert` and solve this issue later by manually copying required files from the backup to the reverted working copy.

Comment: I feared that this is the proper solution. However, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the working copy somewhere else (i.e. make a backup), then run [`svn revert`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html) and solve this issue later by manually copying required files from the backup to the reverted working copy.