# How to undo an add in versions app without reverting

Tags: svn, versions

I use the subversion versions app for mac.  I added a new file (via rightclick->add).  I want to undo this action.  How can I do that without reverting, since I have other local changes that I still want to keep? Can this be done from the versions app itself? I did see this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083242/undo-svn-add-without-reverting-local-edits) but, really would like to know if its doable from within the app.  Also, not sure if that answer applies to my case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned to Dave, I was unable to delete or ignore the file.  I ended up reverting just that file and it went back to its original status as not yet added.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to ignore list the file(s) you want to keep in local.

Comment: Thanks Dave.  Unfortunately when I try to ignore I get the message ```The item “test.php” can't be ignored because it is under version control. Delete it first, then try again.```  When I try to delete I also get an error.

Comment: ```A subversion error occured: 'test.php' has local modifications -- commit or revert them first```  And the whole point was that I didn't want to commit it (and I didn't want to lose the file).  So I tried as suggested - to revert just that one. I originally wasn't sure that would do what I needed, but I had no other option and tried that - and it worked.

Comment: When I asked the question, I thought my only option would be to revert the entire project. I did not want that.  In hindsight it makes sense to have just reverted the one file.